# Why doesn't the dictionary bind to controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

**This is what I am passing to the controller**

```
{
"Name": "8a",
"SubjectsWithTeachers": {
    "Maxim": ["Biology"],
    "Cristy": ["Math", "Chemistry"]
}
}
```

**This is how i am passing**

```
fetch("/Admin/AddClassroom", {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

**Model**

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> SubjectsWithTeacher { get; set; }
```

**In the controller(`AddClassroom([FromBody] ClassroomViewModel cvm)`) I get this**

```
Name = "8a",
SubjectsWithTeachers = null
```

Comment: Which version of asp net core are you using? Newtonsoft JSON or system.json?

Comment: @dariogriffo my .net is 5.0.102. I have not changed anything related to json in the Startup.cs, so probably System.Json

Comment: So yes. You are using system.text.json. read my answer and do an small test program serialising the dictionary and see how is serialised. Hope that helps

Comment: Man I just found the problem. The properties are different. SubjectsWithTeachers Vs SubjectsWithTeacher. At least that's what is on your snippets

Comment: @dariogriffo Thank you very much, I'm so inconsiderate. Could you write this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @dariogriffo it works even with no newtonsoft.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property name on the client side is different from the model property on the back end.
SubjectsWithTeacher Vs SubjectsWithTeachers.
Check the spelling please